# i want get my count in descending order

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to get my count in reverse order

Here is my code

```
def get_products_most_sold(**kwargs):
    code = kwargs['code']
    sales_from = kwargs['from_date']
    sales_to = kwargs['to_date']
    times_sold = products_by_date_store(code, sales_from, sales_to)

    products={}    
    barcodes=times_sold.keys()

    for barcode in barcodes:
        log.info(barcode)
        product=Product.get_by_bacode_storecode(barcode,code)

        if product is not None:
            products[barcode]=product.json()

    return_pr=lambda p: None if products.get(p) is None else products.get(p)
    return_sn=lambda p: None if products.get(p) is None else Supplier.get_supplier_name(products.get(p)['supplier_code'],products.get(p)['store_code'])
    pr = lambda p: {'product':return_pr(p),'count':times_sold.get(p),'supplier_name':return_sn(p)}
    return [pr(item) for item in barcodes]
```

Comment: What you are trying to do ?

Comment: ...then sort it accordingly. What's the problem?

Comment: i want to get my count in reverse order.

Comment: pr = lambda p: {'product':return_pr(p),'count':times_sold.get(p),'supplier_name':return_sn(p)}

Comment: `dict.get` already returns None if the key doesn't exist. `return_pr = products.get`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `sorted` function. and specify the `key` argument as a function which returns count. Use `reverse=True` argument for descending sort.

```
return sorted([pr(item) for item in barcodes], key=lambda item: item['count'], reverse=True)
```

Reference: [python wiki on sorting](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting)